# Forcing Oracle to use Primary Key Index without using Hints

Tags: oracle, optimization, indexing, primary-key

We have an application that generates some temporary tables and then processes the data. I dont really have control of the way the application creates this and the subsequent queries involved. What we have noticed is that Oracle uses a full table scan instead of using the index which is the primary key of the tables. If it used the primary key index the process would run a whole lot faster.

Since I do not have control over the select queries generated by the application I cannot use hints and force Oracle to use primary key index. Is there any other setting I could change somewhere that could force Oracle to use primary key index for the temporary tables?

Comment: Can you add one more column which will have auto increment sequence and set that column as a primary key column

Comment: I am more a MSSQL guy but there the only way to coerce a query is via a hint.  From your wording it is not clear if you have control over the creation of the temporary table.  Are you sure the PK is being created?  If there are PK / FK relationships then are they being declared (in MSSQL the query optimizer uses this)?  I have never had a query not use a PK when it was logical.

Comment: @BalamBalam I do not have control over the creation of the temporary table. However we did check to make sure that the PK was being created. I have no idea why the query optimizer is not using this and its a curious problem because I cannot add any hints to the query.

Comment: @Emmanuel N I have no control over the creation of the new table unfortunately so I cannot add another column

Comment: Are they joining to tables you do have control over?  Make sure the tables you have control over are properly indexed and not fragmented.  Make sure they are building statistics.  You might exercise the tables you have control over to build statistics.   I doubt this will fix anything but it probably won't break anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two most common reasons for a query not using indexes are:

1. It's quicker to do a full table scan.
2. Poor statistics.

If your queries are selecting all of the table or doing joins without mentioning a primary key in the where clause etc., chances are it's quicker to do a full scan. Without the query and indexes, and preferably an explain plan as well it's impossible to tell for certain.

I would, however, recommend that you ask your DBA to re-gather - I hope, if not gather for the first time - statistics on the table. Use [`dbms_stats.gather_table_stats`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm), with an estimate percentage of 25%+.

If the tables are re-created each time the application is run then try and gather statistics after creation and primary key generation. If they are truncated and re-filled each time, then ask your DBA to rebuild them and the PK and then gather statistics as this could significantly increase query runtime.

With no control over anything I don't see how you can improve the query time any other way.

Comment: `With no control over anything I don't see how you can improve the query time any other way.` -> This. Perhaps it's better to gather the entire schema stats as well.

Comment: @Sathya, yes I guess so. I was answering for one query using certain tables but **if** stats have been poorly collected it's worth doing it everywhere.

Comment: Stats are collected for the other tables in the schemaThe application creates the temp table, uses them and drops them when the process finishes so gathering stats can be a problem. Well I guess there is no way to improve query time then.

Comment: @Eosphorus, there are plenty of ways to improve the query but they all need you to have some sort of "power" over what's happening. If there's anyway of adding a gather stats into the middle of the application then I would definitely try it; it shouldn't hurt anything and may massively improve it.

Comment: @Eosphorus You may also want to consider increasing the dynamic sampling level: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/stats.htm#i42991

Comment: well in the ended up gathering stats in the middle of the application and it was a huge improvement

Answer (score 2):

You can use hints without changing SQL by leveraging SQL Profiles. Wrap your hint(s) into a SQL Profile that takes effect for that particular SQL ID.

I understand you don't have control over SQL, I have many apps where I encounter the same restriction. After checking query structure and statistics as in Ben's post and you have proved that hinting to use the index will improve performance why not try a manually created SQL profile.

Christian Antognini has a great paper [here](http://antognini.ch/papers/SQLProfiles_20060622.pdf) about SQL Profiles and creating them manually. The paper mentions creating SQL Profiles manually is undocumented. I would agree undocumented, but that doesn't necessarily mean unsupported. I would say there is little documentation out there, but if you want proof that Oracle allows manual creation, check the API or look at the coe_xfr_sql_profile.sql file in the [SQLT](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2010/07/sqlt-coe_xfr_sql_profilesql/) utility directory.

I also posted a cheatsheet on how to quickly manually create a SQL Profile [here](http://ba6.us/node/119).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This post was immensely helpful. I will look into this